# Porque mi "for" no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript

he hecho un pequeño código para detectar si un string dado tiene todas las letras del abecedario, no se porque porque el "for" de mi codigo no se ejecuta(me he dado cuenta de que no se ejecuta poniendo un return true al principio del for y aun asi me retorna false, aqui mi codigo:

```js
function isPangram(string){
      let arr = string.split("")
      let letras = []

      for(let i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i++) {
        if(arr[i].typeOf == "number") {
          continue
        }

        alert("s")

        if(arr[i] == " ") {
          continue
        }

        if(letras.indexOf(arr[i].toLowerCase()) == -1) {
          letras.push(arr[i].toLowerCase())
        }

        if(letras.length == 26) {
          return true
        }
      }
      return false
    }
```

Comment: Que se supone que hace la funcion, y que caso de prueba nos puedes dar a tratar ?? Es decir, es uan funcion que recibe un string, pero que resultado busca obtener ???

Comment: string es una palabra reservada..    no puede ser nunca el nombre de una variable... de ahi en mas.. ya nada funciona...

Comment: no tiene sentido lo que decís, claro que se puede usar como nombre de variable, y Excorpion en el texto ese lo digo pero bueno, es para detectar si un string tiene todas las letras del abecedario al menos 1 vez

Comment: `length` está mal escrito, "no tiene sentido" el método que estás usando (y para pedir ayuda hay que tratar bien a los demás, como consejo para la vida

Comment: Alfabravo gracias, pero podes decirme cuando trate mal a alguien wtf?

Comment: si es lo de no tiene sentido, no se donde esta la mala educacion en eso , solo es decir a alguien que lo que dice no es correcto, dios mio

Comment: @Jesús el problema al probar el codigo es que tienes por ahora mal escrito el length. corrigelo y sigue probando

Answer (score 2):

hola el for no te esta funcionando por que estas ocupando mal `typeOf` es `typeof(elemento)` te dejo un codigo simplificando esos if que tienes, ademas siempre que tengas un arreglo ya que trabajas con *JavaScript* te recomiendo usar forEach te dejo un codigo de ejemplo sobre tu programa.

```js
function abcdario (texto) {
    const arreglo = texto.split("");
    const abc = []
    arreglo.forEach( (element) => { 
        if (element != " " && // si el elemento es distinto de un espacio
          typeof(element) === "string" && // si el elemento es tipo string
          abc.indexOf(element.toLowerCase()) == -1){ 

            abc.push(element)
        }
    });
    if (abc.length == 26){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
 }
let palabra = "abcdefghij klmnlkkkjujopqrstuvwxyz"      
console.log(abcdario(palabra))
```

Nota: Recuerda que el triple igual `===` además de verificar que sean iguales verifica si su tipo es igual ya que con un doble igual tenemos que `"2" == 2` nos dará `true`

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en que tienes mal escrito el metodo length. Aparte, tu comprabación del tipo no va a funcionar, ya que, `typeof` es una funcion mas no un metodo/propiedad de los elementos.

**Nota:** yo usaria en vez de string otro nombre, para evitar usar nombres clave
de javascript.

```
function isPangram(string){
    let arr = string.split("")
    let letras = []

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(typeof(arr[i]) == "number") {
        continue
      }

      if(arr[i] == " ") {
        continue
      }

      if(letras.indexOf(arr[i].toLowerCase()) == -1) {
        letras.push(arr[i].toLowerCase())
      }

      if(letras.length == 26) {
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }

isPangram("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"); // true
isPangram("abcdefghijklmnostuvwxyz"); // false
```